# Fix permissions on files copied to samba shares automatically

Tags: permissions, files, samba, file-sharing

so I have a samba share where I have multiple groups and user.
in my case:

A user named *CEO* would be a member of groups **Partners** and **Users**,

While user *Clerk* would be just a member of group **Users** .

There are 2 Shared folders, `Common`, and `Partners-only`. Common would be owned by users and Partners-only by Partners.
So the **CEO** can Access both `Common` and `Partners-Only`, while **Clerk** can only Access `Common`.

Now the issue is that when CEO copies something from `Partners-Only` onto `Common`, the permission stay that the file is owned by **Partners** group and any regular user cannot access the file.

I have a fix for it with crontab that goes like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/chgrp  -R Users /mnt/Common/ >> /var/log/permissions/Common.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/chmod  -R g+rw /mnt/Common >> /var/log/permissions/partners.log 2>&1
```

And it works, however, the issue is that with many different groups and shares I have simular cronjob too many times and it puts too much strain on the server.

Is there a way to get samba to adjust permissions on its own when a file is copied?
thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What file system type for all the partitions involved?

Comment: Did you consider using directives `force user` and `force group` in your settings?  Could you post the relevant parts of your `smb.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this ... assuming I have a folder at /mnt/Common:

Change ownership and apply the setgid bit to that folder:

```
sudo chown :users /mnt/Common
sudo chmod 2775 /mnt/Common
```

*The setgid bit will force every new file added on the server itself to this directory to inherit the group of the parent.*

Then create a share definition in smb.conf that looks something like this:

```
[Common]
path = /mnt/Common
valid users = @users @partners
force group = users
writeable = yes
create mask = 0664
force directory mode = 2775
```

When a member of either group adds a file to the share it will save with group = users and permissions of 664. Any new subdirectory added will save with group = users, set folder permissions to 775, and will apply the setgid bit to that subdirectory.